# Adding FK Index to existing table in Merge Replication Topology

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, indexing, merge-replication

I have a table that has grown quite large that we are replicating to about 120 subscribers.  A FK on that table does not have an index and when I ran an Execution Plan on a query that was causing issues it had this to say -->

```
/*
Missing Index Details from CaseNotesTimeoutQuerys.sql - mylocal\sqlexpress.MATRIX (WWCARES\pschaller (54))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 99.5556%.
*/

/*
USE [MATRIX]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[tblCaseNotes] ([PersonID])

GO
*/
```

I would like to add this but I am afraid it will FORCE a reinitialization.  Can anyone verify or validate my concerns?  Does it even work that way or would I need to run the script on each subscriber?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You may want to post this on SO.

Comment: @sims: Done and Thanks.  First response SF = 15 hours.  Not bad.  First response SO = 5 MINUTES, sweet!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965910/adding-fk-index-to-existing-table-in-merge-replication-topology

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to add the index to the publisher & subscriber without it forcing a re-initialization

Comment: Will I need to add it, manually with that script, to each subscriber?  It will not propagate down, correct?

Comment: yes, you need to re-initialize with a snapshot & specify to copy non-clustered indexes, or apply it manually a the subscriber